# Getting info about two users with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem. I am making a Private messages system now, and I need to get user and his rank info to print it on screen. So I do JOIN

```
SELECT 
   private_messages.from    as `from`,
   private_messages.to      as `to`,
   private_messages.theme   as `theme`,
   private_messages.date    as `date`,
   private_messages.message as `message`,
   users.username           as `username`,
   users.id                 as `user_id`,
   private_messages.id      as `pm_id`,
   ranks.style              as `style`,
   ranks.rank_name          as `rank_name`
FROM `private_messages` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON private_messages.from = users.id
LEFT JOIN `ranks` ON users.rank            = ranks.id
WHERE   private_messages.id=? LIMIT 1
```

But the problem is that I get only info about user 'from' (who sended a message) and dont get rank and other things about user 'to' (who received a message) and I need his info too and don't know what to do, can anyone help me? :)

Comment: Maybe you can use something like `LEFT JOIN users ON private_messages.from = users.id OR private_messages.to = users.id`

Comment: Still getting just one user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want infor about two user you must join two time the table user one for user_from an one for user_to ...

this is just a suggestion for getting info for two users

```
SELECT 
    private_messages.from as `from`,
    private_messages.to as `to`,
    private_messages.theme as `theme`,
    private_messages.date as `date`,
    private_messages.message as `message`,
    users.username as `username`,
    users_to.username as `username_to`
    users.id as `user_id`,
    private_messages.id as `pm_id`,
    ranks.style as `style`,
    ranks.rank_name as `rank_name`
    FROM `private_messages` 
    INNER JOIN `users` ON private_messages.from = users.id
    INNER JOIN `users` as user_to ON private_messages.to = users.id
    LEFT JOIN `ranks` ON users.rank = ranks.id
    WHERE   private_messages.id=? LIMIT 1
```

Comment: any error, just array === false when private_messages.id != 1 i dont know why. and still getting just 1 user info :/

Comment: Just for debug .. check if your private_message.id = 1 is properly formatted with correct value for user_form e user_to.. and try without left join ranks for test ..